# Android: why buttons event not working after press back button?

Tags: android

I have defined four buttons that onclick event shows a content, now after click when press

**back button** that shows same four buttons but click event not working.
I defined a field that if user saw content isLooked=true so when clicked on back button I  setContentView(R.layout.index) and I will not allow to exit of current activity.
why not working events after click on back button?

```
 private boolean isLooked = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.index);
            initialEvents();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new com.example.csharp.Log.Error().Save(e);
        }
    }

    private void initialEvents() {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.btnChapter1);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v = findViewById(R.id.btnChapter2);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v = findViewById(R.id.btnChapter3);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v = findViewById(R.id.btnChapter4);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isLooked) {
            setContentView(R.layout.index);
            isLooked = false;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isLooked) {
            setContentView(R.layout.index);
            isLooked = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnChapter1:
            setContentView(R.layout.chapter1_index);
            isLooked = true;
            break;

        case R.id.btnChapter2:
            setContentView(R.layout.chapter2_index);
            isLooked = true;
            break;
        case R.id.btnChapter3:
            setContentView(R.layout.chapter3_index);
            isLooked = true;
            break;

        case R.id.btnChapter4:
            setContentView(R.layout.chapter4_index);
            isLooked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting new content view when back pressed, this is create a new instance of objects for the layout set. But your on click listener is set for the view set in onCreate.

If you really want to set content on back pressed, then you have to findViewById again and set the listener.

Comment: Do you have any solution that I have not to set the listener again?

Comment: don't set the content view on back press

Comment: So how to show **before layout** without using a new activity?